# i want to have <div> and want to set my <div> (block) in rows and 3 column so please check my code

Tags: php, html, css

My code is  below and i want to create a dynamic box type structure on my page of having rows and 3 column but the result shows only one column and many rows (and i am new in programming):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php

include("connect.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";
$filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result)){
echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='block'>";
 echo "<div class='boxed'>";

 echo "<div id='container'>";


 echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" ."<br>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>"."<br>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['created_date'] . "</td>"."<br>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td>"."<br>";

 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";


  }
?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and the css file is:

```
   .boxed {
   border: 1px solid green ;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  margin: 25px;
  color: #FF9900;
 background-color: #000000;
 align:center;
  }
#container {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

#left {
float:left;
width:100px;
}

#center {
display: inline-block;
margin:0 auto;
width:100px;
}

#right {
float:right;
width:100px;
}
.row {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
width: 100px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

output:

Answer (score 1):

You are missing with `<table>` and `<tr>` tag. Please add it in your code. Use below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php

include("connect.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";
$filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result)){
echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='block'>";
 echo "<div class='boxed'>";

 echo "<div id='container'>";

 echo "<table><tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" ."<br>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>"."<br>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['created_date'] . "</td>"."<br>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td>"."<br>";
  echo "</table></tr>";

 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";


  }
?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: actually after adding the <table> and <tr> tag, problem remain same...bcoz i want to placed my box in a grid manner(rows and column)....anyway thanx sir and help me
for eg- visit:https://github.com/Igalia/css-grid-layout/blob/gh-pages/gallery.png

Comment: do you need it in table tag ? Can you please add desire output? @DevelopmentTechlab

Comment: please check https://github.com/Igalia/css-grid-layout/blob/gh-pages/calendar.png
want such type of pattern